# how to handle download request from a WebView using WebResourceRequestFilter blackberry Cascades

Tags: qt, blackberry, webview, download

i want to handle any download request coming from  Webview. how it is possible ? the documentation https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__webresourcerequestfilter.html and https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__webdownloadrequest.html are describing the parameters but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear on what you don't understand.  Remember this is not a training forum, the idea is that you should try things, review the documentation and then ask specific questions to get the best out of a forum.

Moreover it is not clear whether you are trying to handle the download request at the Server, or capture the request before the download attempt leaves the BB.

I'm going to assume you want to display a web page on the BlackBerry but make sure that any resource requests that the page generates, are filtered by your program, so that you can supply the data (assuming you have it).

I implemented something like this a while ago and remember that it was not simple to figure out what was going on, but I played with it a bit and it all made sense.

I don't remember using WebDownloadRequest and can't really see how it helps in this case.

The key is WebResourceRequestFilter.  You create your own WebResourceRequestFilter making sure you implement the required methods.  Then you use WebPage::setNetworkResourceRequestFilter(WebResourceRequestFilter*) to make sure the webpage will ask your WebResourceRequestFilter for its resources.  The first method the web page invokes is filterResourceRequest(), and the return from this invocation determines which other methods in your WebResourceRequestFilter, the Webage will invoke.

I suggest you implement a WebResourceRequestFilter, put some debugging in filterResourceRequest(), but always return FilterAction Accept, which means the web page will use its normal processing to obtain the resources.  Then try various other FilterAction return values and see what happens...